# How to implement JTable inside a cell of another JTable and how can I implement column name from database?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I do not know much about `JTable` and I am trying to develop an application contains  one.

In the app. I need to put a `JTable2` inside a `JTable1` also `jtable2` needs to have Row Header  and I have more than 56 column Header that I want to implement directly from a database. I am using `AbstractTableModel`
so I am asking for your help to advise me what and how to do it.

This is the code that I used is like the one below:

```
package sqgemcom;

import ch.swingfx.twinkle.NotificationBuilder;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import main.java.ch.swingfx.twinkle.style.theme.DarkDefaultNotification;

public class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel{
java.sql.ResultSetMetaData   rsmd;
int colonne ;
    int ligne;
    ArrayList<Fpy> data = new ArrayList<Fpy>();
        Fpy Fpy;
        public MyModel(ResultSet rst)
        {
            try {
            rsmd=rst.getMetaData();
            colonne= rsmd.getColumnCount();
            while(rst.next()){
                Fpy= new Fpy(rst.getString(1),rst.getString(2),rst.getString(3),rst.getString(4),rst.getString(5),rst.getString(6),rst.getString(7));
            data.add(Fpy);
            ligne++;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            new NotificationBuilder().withStyle(new DarkDefaultNotification()).withTitle("Erreur")
            .withMessage("Model :impossible d'afficher la table, verifier votre connexion").withDisplayTime(3000).showNotification();
        }
        }
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return ligne;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colonne;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int lin, int col) {
       Fpy e=data.get(lin);
       String ch="";
       switch (col)
           {case 0:
            ch=(e.getId()).toString()   ;           
            break;
        case 1:
            ch=(e.getProduit()).toString();         
            break;
        case 2:
            ch=e.getOperation();            
            break;
               case 3:
        ch=(e.getQuantité_demarree()).toString()    ;               
                break;

               case 4:

            ch=(e.getQuantité_complétée()).toString();              
                    break;


               case 5:

            ch=(e.getSemaine()).toString();             
                    break;

               case 6:
            ch=(e.getFpy()).toString()  ;               
                break;  

               default:
            break;
        }
        return ch;
    }
    public String getColumnName(int l) {
        try {
            return rsmd.getColumnName(l+1);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

something like this i want to be able to make cells inside a cell,, me table is like a tree :i have a lot of products each one has 2 code and every code has different cell what i mean is that

[image]

Comment: You can't add a JTable into a cell of another JTable.

Comment: Your question may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely. Consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: i may not explained what i what to do exactly so i updated my post and i tried to explain my problem

Comment: `i want to be able to make cells inside a cell,` - and you already have your answer. See the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

> needs to have Row Header and I have more than 56 column Header that I want to implement directly from a database

You get the column names from the meta data of the ResultSet:

```
String sql = "Select * from ???";
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );
ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
int columns = md.getColumnCount();
Vector<Object> columnNames = new Vector<Object>(columns);

//  Get column names

for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
{
    columnNames.addElement( md.getColumnName(i) );
}

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);

// add ResultSet row data to the model

....

JTable table = new JTable( model );
```

Comment: thank you but the problem is that the 56 are not colones in my database they are the content of a colone